# Anyone transition from ASP.NET(MVC) to Play Framework

Tags: playframework

Been a long time user of the Microsoft stack and looking at other frameworks to learn and maybe transition to. I ran across the Play Framework recently and started working through some of the demos and really like it. Anyone from a .NET background transition to Play and if so what has been your experience so far?

Comment: Remeber that the Scala templates for Play Framework are inspired from the ASP.NET MVC Razor template engine, so they may be familiar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ive mostly written projects using ASP.NET MVC/C#/SQL server but choose to experiment with Play/Java/Postgres in a recent project.

On the whole Im quite productive with Play, specific things I like include:

- The way in which views are compiled which greatly helps spot typos
- The futures and promise framework
- Very easy to package and deploy, i.e. play stage
- Ability to write and include plugins in just a few lines of code
- The fact that caching is built in

Potential disadvantages

- Can take a while to compile which can be annoying during development/testing
- Documentation is not always as detailed or extensive compared with ASP.NET MVC
- Availability of code samples
- The fact that the http context is lost during async events (i think it has since been fixed in play 2.1)
- I find the membership provider and config of role permissions in the web.config file easier to work with compared with the Play Secured class (then you dont need to specifically annotate each controller/method)
- No LINQ within Java (Not a fault of Play itself) but if you use scala then you can use lamda expressions
  -

Comment: Hello, Which IDE you used to code play framework website?

Comment: It's probably too late, but I would strongly advise IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

Not personally, but a workmate has done the following path for his own personal projects (quite a geek the guy): C# => Scala for .net => Play with Scala.

He's quite happy about Play (and the fact that I stopped pushing him to try it :P), I'll ask him to post later about his experience with more detail, but the key points of Play (simplicity, quick turnaround, etc) still apply for him.

Comment: Hi Pere..that would be great to see what his experience has been with Play coming from .NET.

Comment: Told him, now it's up to him... :P

Comment: Hey Pere. Bug your workmate about posting his experiences with Play coming from a .NET background. I think alot of people would be interested in hearing about this.

Comment: Yes, I'm on it... lazy guy :(